# Calculate large decimals (more than 15 digits) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal, cryptocurrency

As we know, Javascript has some issues (or features) with calculating decimal numbers. For example:

```js
console.log(0.1 + 0.2) // 0.30000000000000004
```

And we know that we can avoid it using different libraries (for example I use [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)), and now we have what expected:

```js
console.log(Number(new BigNumber(0.1).plus(0.2))); // 0.3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/6.0.0/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```

**BUT**

Bignumber.js has limitations:

> It accepts a value of type number (up to 15 significant digits only),
>   string or BigNumber object.

We can pass a string (it's possible), but this way we can lost some digits from the end:

```js
console.log(Number(new BigNumber(0.1).plus("198.43092534959501"))); // 198.530925349595, not 198.53092534959501
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/6.0.0/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```

Now I work with cryptocurrencies and often I deal with numbers like `198.43092534959501`, and in this case I get an error (as expected):

```js
console.log(Number(new BigNumber(0.1).plus(198.43092534959501))); // error
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/6.0.0/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```

I know that some people uses additional multipliers, but it will not work in the case provided above. If you deal with cryptocurrencies, you know, that we actually work with non-multiplied and multiplied values (like `489964999999000000` and `0.489964999999`). But my goal for now is to sum all fiat balances for different currencies, but they have different multipliers, so I can't just sum non-multiplied values, and looks like I need to sum multiplied values somehow.

It was a small background, but my general **question is:**

How to sum/multiply/etc. decimal numbers, which have more than 15 digits?

Comment: I think you answered your own question in the background. It says BigNumber will accept a number formatted as a string as input.

Comment: `0.1` is not a decimal number but a floating point data type. And those floating point data types are not suitable for decimal calculations because they serve a different purpose. And that’s not only the case for JS but for any other language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I already answered this in the comment, but here's a demonstration. BigNumber will accept a number in string format for input.

```js
console.log(new BigNumber(0.1).plus("198.43092534959501"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/6.0.0/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you, but in this case the last 2 digits are lost. Is there a way to keep the full number?

Comment: Don't covert it back to a `Number` and you keep whatever number of digits you have BigDecimal configured to use, right?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The last digits were lost because your sample cast it back to a number. Just keep the numbers as string or BigNumber at all times.

Comment: Good answer, thank you (and to @ScottSauyet too)! I was hoping that we can do it with numbers, but if not - it's ok, I'll adjust myself. Thanks again!

Comment: There's no way to keep this degree of accuracy in JavaScript. The number of bits resolution is included in the language specification, so libraries are required to handle anything this large. I struggled with the same while playing with crypto-key file formats in NodeJS.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do it with numbers.  If JS Numbers could handle this, then there would be no need for the BigNumber library or its peers.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, thank you, good suggestion. The main idea is more clear for me now.